# Prove that $U+W = \{u+w\mid u\in U, w\in W\}$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$ and let $U,W$ be finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Prove that $U+W = \{u+w\mid u\in U, w\in W\}$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$.

I know how to prove that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $V$ but I'm having a hard time grasping how to prove $U+W$

This is what I was doing in regards to the first part of proving closed under addition:

Let $u,w\in U+W$ and $u\in U, w\in W$

Since $U$ is a space, it is closed under addition and $u+w\in U$. Also, $W$ is a space so it is closed under addition as well and so $u+w \in W$. So, $u+w\in W$ and $u+w\in W$ shows that $u+w\in U+W$. Thus, $U+W$ is closed under addition.

But this is almost exactly how I've proved $U\cap W$ is a subspace and I have a feeling I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Standard MathJax usage is not $U+W$ = {$u+w | u\in U, w\in W$}, but $U+W = \{u+w\mid u\in U, w\in W\}$, all between just one pair of dollar signs, and with \mid. When the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ are not inside the pair of dollar signs, then the fonts and font sizes don't match and there is not proper spacing.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: You can also directly show that $U + W$ is a *finite-dimensional* subspace of $V$ by taking a basis of $U$, a basis of $W$, and showing that their union spans $U + W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $U + W$ is a subspace of $V$ it must be shown that $U + W$ contains the the zero vector, is closed under addition and is closed under scalar multiplication. Showing the zero vector is in $U + W$ is very easy. Since $U, W$ are subspaces of V, $0 \in U,V.$ Thus, $0 + 0 = 0 \in U + W.$ Now let $x, y \in U + W.$ This means $ x = a + b$ for some $a \in U$ and $b \in W$ and $y = c + d$ for some $c \in U$ and $d \in W.$ Now, $x + y = (a + b) + (c + d) = (a + c) + (b + d).$ Since a,c $\in U$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ $a + c \in U.$ The same argument can be made for $b + d \in W.$ Thus, $x + y \in U + W$ and $U + W$ is closed under addition. Showing $U + W$ is closed under scalar multiplication is similar and I leave it to you to work out.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $U+W$ is closed under addition, you need to assume two elements in $U+W$, and show their addition is also in $U+W$.

So let $v\in U+W$ and $v'\in U+W$. Suppose $v=u+w, v'=u'+w'$, where $u,u'\in U$ and $w,w'\in W$.

Then $v+v'=(u+u')+(w+w')$. This is in $U+W$ since $U$ and $W$ are closed under addition, thus $u+u'\in U$ and $w+w'\in W$.

Comment: did you mean $u+u'\in U$ in your second sentence?

Comment: @LindseyG: No, I meant my original assumption was $u,u'\in U$ and $w,w'\in W$.

Answer (score 0):

"Closed under addition" means that $u+w \in U$ would be true if $u,w \in U.$ Written more concisely, $$U + U \subseteq U.$$ It's not enough when $u \in U$ and $w$ isn't. This is why your proof doesn't work.

You can make a proof around the computation $$(U+W) + (U+W) = (U+U) + (W+W) \subseteq U + W.$$

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for $u+w$ to be in $U$ since $w$ doesn't necessarily belong to $U$.

What you have to prove is that, if $u+w\in U+W$, $u'+w'\in U+W$ ($u,u'\in U$, $w,w'\in W$) then  $(u+w)+(u'+w')$ has the form $(u''+w'')$ for some $u''\in U , w''\in W$, and similarly for $\lambda (u+w)$.